# need a very tiny (rectangular in shape) overlay over UIImagePickerController, and then crop the image accordingly - UPDATED

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimagepickercontroller

In my application, i need the user to take a snap of only a 10 letter word (using `overlay`, which should be right in the centre of the screen of the `UIImagePicker`), and then in need to show him that image (only the part of the image covered by that rectangle). So, I need to crop that image according to the overlay.

Here, i have taken a picture using UIImagePickerControl. Now, i want to see the dimensions of the image that i have taken..

```
UIImage *imageToprocess = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

NSLog(@"image width %f", imageToprocess.size.width);
NSLog(@"image height %f", imageToprocess.size.height);
```

I see the following result on console.. But how is this possible. the dimensions of the image is exceeding the dimension of the iPhone screen size.. (which is 320, 568)

```
UsingTesseractOCR[524:60b] image width 2448.000000
2013-12-17 16:02:18.962 UsingTesseractOCR[524:60b] image height 3264.000000
```

Can anybody help me out here?? I have gone through several questions here, but did not understand how to do it.

Please help..

Answer (score 0):

Refer this sample code for image capturing and cropping.

https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/CropImageSample

Answer (score 0):

For creating overlay, first create a custom view (of full dimensions of camera preview) and add an transparent image with just a rectangle in its background. use this view as overlay view.

```
  myview =[[UIImageView alloc]init];
  myview.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 431); 

 // why 431? bcoz height = height of device - height of tabbar present in the
   bottom for camera controls of picker
//for iphone 4 ,480-49

  myview.backgroundColor =[UIColor clearColor];
  myview.opaque = NO;
  myview.image =[UIImage imageNamed:@"A45Box.png"];
  myview.userInteractionEnabled =YES;
```

note that you create a background image appropriately (means dimensions). You can also draw rectangle programmatically but this is much easy way.

Secondly, talking about your cropping issue, you have to get your hands dirty....Try these links for help
https://github.com/iosdeveloper/ImageCropper

https://github.com/barrettj/BJImageCropper

https://github.com/ardalahmet/SSPhotoCropperViewController